# UITableView load height

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there a way to load a table view that opens at the second or third section (rather than at the top)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the IndexPath to the Section, you can use the following UITableView Method:

```
scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
```

Have a look at the documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: